# How can I mass produce confetti?

Tags: paper

In a relatively close future, I will be attending an event in which a very large amount of confetti would be appreciated. As in, litres of them.

These would have to be produced in the smallest time possible at minimal cost, and if possible with common household tools.

I already have considerable amounts of draft paper aside for the occasion.

[Wikihow](http://m.wikihow.com/Make-Confetti) doesn't help : its tips are either too slow, or with tools I don't have ( shredder or paper guillotine  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cutting the first few sheets of paper by hand to make confetti will go well until you get into cutting up the thin strips which do not want to cooperate. You will slow down to a crawl.

You must automate this process.

To produce the confetti yourself, use a cross-cut paper shredder which produces chips/chads instead of strips of paper produced by most others.
Place the shredder over a large waste paper basket lined with a garbage bag so that you won't have to empty it often.

You can borrow, or rent a shredder if you look around and try the various flea markets and used equipment online listings. Advertise in the listings to make a contact to get the job done.

If you can get your paper supplied in rolls, you can feed several ends into the mouth of the shredder at one time and it will be self-feeding. You can use up to 6 rolls of 20 lb/85 gsm paper stock.

Paper when "fluffed up" this way will produce up to 50 times the original volume so have plenty of bags handy for the amount you will produce.

You can visit a paper shredder company such as Shred-it to generate massive amounts of your supplied paper as well as a do-it-yourself. Bring your own paper as they treat all materials as confidential and cannot supply their customer's waste for you.

Comment: OP specifically said he doesn't have (access to) a shredder.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Well, there were other alternatives given to gain access to one. There were other ideas to try as well. I'm going to bet that the OP will "find" one after the first sheet of paper cut by hand. : (

Comment: @ZeissIkon I just checked. A paper shredder is cheaper than a guillotine paper cutter. Paper shredders are also now more common and safer to use than a large guillotine cutter necessary to cut multiple sheets.

Comment: OTOH, depending where the OP works, he might have access to a guillotine cutter without purchasing a new one.

Comment: I like the roll auto-feed thing ! But I really don't have access to a shredder, at home or at work. If @Stan 's answer doesn't work, I might look for such shredding companies.

Comment: If one asks nicely, it might be possible to use the shredder at an office or similar that handles sensitive paper on a daily basis, yet not enough to justify calling a shredding service. Small lawyer offices, banks,... Some might even let you use their "confetti" if you don't need a specific colour. Side note: state bank even sells confetti out of old bank notes.

Answer (score 2):

A "guillotine" style paper cutter is likely to be most efficient for this.  It will cut stacks of paper (older, heavier units will cut a dozen sheets or more; even the new ones that are mostly plastic will cut five sheets).  Cut a narrow strip from a stack of sheets, shift over, and cut another.  Cut as many as you can without risking your fingers, then collect the strips you've cut and cut the ends (length similar to width) to make your confetti.

You can convert a full stack of sheets to confetti, leaving a handling strip and some tag ends, in a few minutes.  To make liters will take time, but almost certainly less time than anything else other than a crosscut shredder.

Comment: I updated my question to explicit the fact I don't have a paper cutter

Answer (score 2):

Use a kitchen shredder.

You can try other types of "shredders" such as a blender or a food processor if the confetti can be various sized chips of paper. Making confetti with food processing equipment is easy but the quality of the product is low.

It's worth a try since different equipment produces different results. Your mileage may vary.

You cannot process as much paper this way as the container fills quickly and must be emptied often. The process gets messy very quickly. There's more dust produced this way if you're not careful or not paying attention.

Comment: You are a genius. I'll try it out and if it is good enough I'll validate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once I used an [hole puncher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punch) to create confetti for carnival. If you have enough time [you can get one from Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/paper-punches/b?ie=UTF8&node=12898081). I remember I used a [double hole puncher](http://www.lime-office.com.au/img/productImages/open/430837.jpg) with multiple and colorful sheets of paper, like a magazine. I've stacked them and punched altogheter, speeding the process. The confetti were really beautiful, all round and perfect. It was fun and relatively fast!

I was young, 10-12 y.o., so if you have children you can let them play with it with no risks.

Comment: I had considered this option, but it is too slow. I really need tons of confetti !

Answer (score 0):

While thinking about this problem i came up with an idea :

1. Use old workbooks instead of draft
2. Cut them from spine to edge with a utility knife to make strips

   - these shouldn't get too close to the spine to avoid ripping at step 3
3. Cut them **again** this time diagonally to make little pieces

To be clearer : Behold for paint skills !
[image: This really was made in Pinta, not MS Paint]

This does have a problem, so I'm not sure I'll do it: I already have lots of draft asside, so using workbooks will be a waste of paper.